# Group action on a manifold with finitely many orbits

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-actions

I'm looking for a result along the lines of the following:

> Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$.  If the action partitions $X$ into finitely many $G$-orbits, then $\dim G \geq \dim X$.

For this to even make sense, it seems like $G$ and $X$ should have a vector space/manifold structure, but there may very well be additional assumptions for the conclusion to hold (for instance, $G$ is also an algebraic group, and the action is polynomial, etc.).

Can someone provide a more complete statement/proof of this result?

This result is used in Tits' argument in Gabriel's theorem (see for example page 29 of Bernstein, Gel'fand, and Ponomarev's article "Coxeter functors and Gabriel's theorem"), but I would also be interested to see how this result may be used in larger contexts.

Comment: Presumably you can sharpen the statement by assuming that $G$ acts faithfully, in which case you get equality for the dimensions of $X$ and $G$.

Comment: @Earthling: Is that a known result?  Do you have a reference for it?

Comment: Each orbit of $G$ is a homogeneous space $G/H$ for some $H$, and in any reasonable setting where "dimension" makes sense these should have dimension less than or equal to $G$ and $X$ should be the disjoint union of the orbits.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: So are you saying that the result is true more or less as I have stated it?  That is, the only assumptions needed are that the notions of dimension make sense?  Also, the finiteness assumption on the number of orbits is to guarantee that the dimension of each orbit has the same dimension as $X$, right?

Comment: @JHF: no, it's needed to guarantee that $X$ is the disjoint union (by which I mean coproduct in the corresponding category) of the orbits. The result should be true in either smooth manifolds or varieties; I hesitate to speculate further than that. In smooth manifolds you may need to assume that $G$ is compact...?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Hmm... I thought that orbits of a group action were always disjoint.  I guess I don't understand this material as well as I should.  Also, why do you think $G$ needs to be compact?  In the application of the result I cited (on Gabriel's theorem), $G$ is some direct sum of $GL(n_i,k)$, which is not compact.  Anyway, thank you for your help.  Any additional information you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JHF: that's not the problem, the problem is that $X$ might not be the coproduct of the orbits. Consider, for example, $S^1$ acting on the first factor of $S^1 \times S^1$. As a *set*, $S^1 \times S^1$ is the disjoint union of the orbits, but as a topological space the disjoint union of the orbits carries a different topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof in the smooth category. Let $\alpha : G \times X \to X$ be an action of a Lie group $G$ on a smooth manifold $X$. For $x \in X$, the image of the map $\alpha(-, x) : G \to X$ is the orbit containing $x$. If $\dim G \lt \dim X$, then by [Sard's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem) the image of $\alpha(-, x)$ has measure zero for any $x$, and consequently $X$ cannot be the union of finitely or even countably many orbits.